# pandas breaking change 1.2.4 versus 1.3.2

Tags: python, pandas

My code broke when I upgraded from pandas 1.2.4 to 1.3.2
There is a ton of changes in the 1.3.x release notes

Do you know what specifically broke this:

1)
Replacing NaN with None (**OLD** works in 1.2.4 not 1.3.2)

**OLD**: `df = df.where(pd.notnull(df), None)`

**NEW**: `df = df.replace({np.nan: None})`

I updated the **OLD** with the **NEW** and it works in both versions.
(a) Anyone know what specifically is the breaking change in the release notes, and (b) is the **NEW** method acceptable for replacing NaN with None?

2)
When I concat two dataframes with None and Bools, the bool was changed to a 1.0, and i needed to replace 1 with True after.

Same question. Anyone know the specific breaking change

example data:

```
    date     type  sub_type 
0  202002       a       NaN 
1  202006       b       NaN 
2  202008       c       NaN 
3  202004       d       NaN 
4  202010       d       NaN 
5  202002       d       NaN 
6  202005       e       NaN 
7  202007       f       NaN 
8  202003       a       NaN
```

Both OLD and NEW convert NaN-None in 1.2.4, and only NEW works in 1.3.2

Comment: You need to give us a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

For an explaination and link to commit of breaking change, see discussion on Pandas issue tracker

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/42423

For 1(b) - I think your new [also has an issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/35268) in v1.4

I think the safest is:

`pd.replace(np.NaN, None)` for latest versions